# Can't figure out where my getter method goes wrong (Java)

Tags: java

The assignment was to create a LinkedElement class on top of a given template with methods like a getter and a remover. I think my add method works fine but I don't seem to understand where my getter method is going wrong.

```
public class LinkedElement<T> {

private T name;
private LinkedElement Link;

public LinkedElement(T value) {
    this.name = value;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of the i-th linked element, assuming the current element to
 * be at index 0.
 * 
 * @param i 0-based index of the element whose value to return.
 * @return the i-th element's value, or {@code null} if there is no element with
 *         that index.
 */
public T get(int i) {
    int iterator = i;
    if (iterator == 0) {
        return this.name;
    } 
    if (iterator > 0) {
        iterator = iterator - 1;
        this.Link.get(iterator);

    }
    return null;

}

/**
 * Adds a new linked element holding the given value at the end of the linked
 * elements.
 * 
 * @param newVal the new value.
 */
public void add(T newVal) {
    if (this.Link == null) {
        this.Link = new LinkedElement(newVal);
    } else {
        this.Link.add(newVal);
    }

}
```

I used this code to test my class. **I expected the second line to be "Whats" but instead I get a null.**
I tried debugging the code in Eclipse but I can't seem to figure out where the problem lies.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedElement<String> headElement = new LinkedElement<String>("Yo!");
    headElement.add("Whats");
    System.out.println(headElement.get(0));          // prints "Yo!"
    System.out.println(headElement.get(1));          // prints "Whats"

}
```

Comment: You should have access to a debugger if you are using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ. Stepping through it may give you insight into what your code is doing and where your assumptions might be incorrect.

Comment: Hint: When you return from a method, it only returns to one step up along the callstack.  It doesn't go straight back to the main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the result in the branch.

```
if (iterator > 0) {
    iterator = iterator - 1;
    return this.Link.get(iterator);
}
```

You also need to change

```
private LinkedElement Link;
```

to

```
private LinkedElement<T> Link;
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of this.Link.get(iterator) should be returned.

```
if (iterator > 0) {
    iterator = iterator - 1;
    this.Link.get(iterator);
}
```

^^Here You just invoke it but never use the result of it. So your code leaves the if statement and returns the Null.

edit: And for your aother question i. the comment: Add type parameter to the instance variable of Link: `private LinkedElement<T> Link;`

Answer (score 0):

You never return in the `iterator > 0` case. It's likely you meant

```
if (iterator > 0) {
    iterator = iterator - 1;
    return this.Link.get(iterator);
}
```

In your current code, the `iterator > 0` case does some assignments and function calls, then completely discards and ignores them, opting to return `null` instead.

Comment: First off thank you for your reply. I think I've tried this earlier but I couldn't really do much with it because Eclipse throws the following error: **Type mismatch:  cannot convert from Object to T.** This error is one of the things that frustrated me while I was trying to figure the solution out.

Comment: It shouldn't show that error. You clearly return T.

Comment: Thought so too, but for some reason Eclipse tells me otherwise. Eclipse suggested me to add a cast ( return (T) this.Link.get(iterator); ) and that seemed to do the trick but I don't know if that's really the right way to do it.

Comment: Add T Type to the Link:private LinkedElement<T> Link;